# VIdeo overlays another incorrectly - background is over overlay

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm a new user of FFmpeg, and I want to insert a logo on two videos (one video overlay another) with one command.

1. FFmpeg command (ok):

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i background1080p.mp4 -i input1080p.mp4 -i
logo.png -filter_complex
"[1]scale=1280:720[inner];[0][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[vid];
[vid][2]overlay=10:10:enable='not(between(t\,10\,15))'[out]" -map
"[out]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -y -shortest output.mp4
```

[image: Good result video]
When I use the above command, it works ok.

2. FFmpeg command error

However, when I apply it to the command line below, I get an error:

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT=D:\Shorts\code\INPUT
set OUTPUT=D:\Shorts\code\OUTPUT

:: encode video:

for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -stream_loop -1 -i background.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=1280:720[inner];[0][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[vid]; [vid][2]overlay=10:10:enable='not(between(t\,10\,15))'[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -shortest "%output%\%%~na_%%03d.mp4"

pause
```

[image: Wrong overlay result]

- Main video (from `INPUT` folder) video and `background.mp4` have their roles the other way round and what's supposed to be the  overlay is the background.

Please help me fix the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of the first two inputs i.e. `-stream_loop -1 -i background.mp4 -i "%%a"`

Comment: I have a question, can you help?

Specifically: with the above code, I want to insert a green video file (this green video file is also looped on "main video" - (colorkey=0x00ff00:0.3:0.2)

So what do we have to deal with?

Comment: Post a new question for that.